# WPF - creating content for a tabitem dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, tabitem

I'd like to set the content of a tabitem dynamically, based on the content/actions taken on previous tabitems.

I'm advancing through the tabs via a command like:

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex++;
```

However, the Loaded event doesn't get fired after this like I thought it would.  tabControl1_SelectionChanged() is getting called, however.  Should I manually call the tabitem's Load() event from SelectionChanged(), or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load will get called only once for every TabItem. but you can get the required TabItem instance from the SelectionChanged and set its content